# Sorting country list alphabeticaly

Tags: javascript, html

I coded the following list based on the countries 2 letter code

Now my boss whats the actually country names in alphetical order. I'm just about to start it manually but would love to know if there is a easy/quick way to do it based on that I have already.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button"     data-toggle="dropdown">Country List <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul style="height: 450px; overflow: auto;" class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AD')">Andorra</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AG')">Antigua and Barbuda</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AI')">Anguilla</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AL')">Albania</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AM')">Armenia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AQ')">Antarctica</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AR')">Argentina</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AT')">Austria</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AU')">Australia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AX')">Aland Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AZ')">Azerbaijan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BA')">Bosnia and Herzegovina</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BB')">Barbados</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BD')">Bangladesh</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BE')">Belgium</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BF')">Burkina Faso</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BG')">Bulgaria</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BI')">Burundi</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BJ')">Benin</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BL')">Saint Barthélemy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BM')">Bermuda</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BN')">Brunei Darussalam</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BO')">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BR')">Brazil</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BS')">Bahamas</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BT')">Bhutan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BV')">Bouvet Island</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BW')">Botswana</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BY')">Belarus</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CA')">Canada</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CC')">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CD')">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CF')">Central African Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CG')">Congo</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CH')">Switzerland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CI')">Côte d'Ivoire</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CK')">Cook Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CL')">Chile</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CM')">Cameroon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CN')">China</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CO')">Colombia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CR')">Costa Rica</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CV')">Cape Verde</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CX')">Christmas Island</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CY')">Cyprus</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CZ')">Czech Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DE')">Germany</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DJ')">Djibouti</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DK')">Denmark</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DM')">Dominica</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DO')">Dominican Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('EC')">Ecuador</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('EE')">Estonia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('EG')">Egypt</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('EH')">Western Sahara</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ES')">Spain</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FI')">Finland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FJ')">Fiji</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FK')">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FM')">Micronesia, Federated States of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FO')">Faroe Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FR')">France</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GA')">Gabon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GB')">United Kingdom</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GD')">Grenada</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GE')">Georgia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GF')">French Guiana</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GG')">Guernsey</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GH')">Ghana</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GI')">Gibraltar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GL')">Greenland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GM')">Gambia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GN')">Guinea</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GP')">Guadeloupe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GQ')">Equatorial Guinea</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GR')">Greece</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GT')">Guatemala</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GU')">Guam</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GW')">Guinea-Bissau</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GY')">Guyana</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HK')">Hong Kong</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HM')">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HN')">Honduras</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HR')">Croatia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HT')">Haiti</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HU')">Hungary</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ID')">Indonesia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IE')">Ireland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IM')">Isle of Man</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IN')">India</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IO')">British Indian Ocean Territory</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IR')">Iran, Islamic Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IS')">Iceland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IT')">Italy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('JE')">Jersey</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('JM')">Jamaica</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('JP')">Japan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KE')">Kenya</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KG')">Kyrgyzstan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KH')">Cambodia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KI')">Kiribati</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KM')">Comoros</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KN')">Saint Kitts and Nevis</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KP')">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KR')">Korea, Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KY')">Cayman Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KZ')">Kazakhstan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LA')">Lao People's Democratic Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LB')">Lebanon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LC')">Saint Lucia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LI')">Liechtenstein</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LK')">Sri Lanka</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LS')">Lesotho</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LT')">Lithuania</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LU')">Luxembourg</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LV')">Latvia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LY')">Libya</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MA')">Morocco</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MC')">Monaco</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MD')">Moldova, Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ME')">Montenegro</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MG')">Madagascar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MK')">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ML')">Mali</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MM')">Myanmar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MN')">Mongolia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MO')">Macao</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MP')">Northern Mariana Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MQ')">Martinique</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MS')">Montserrat</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MU')">Mauritius</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MV')">Maldives</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MW')">Malawi</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MX')">Mexico</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MY')">Malaysia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MZ')">Mozambique</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NA')">Namibia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NC')">New Caledonia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NE')">Niger</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NG')">Nigeria</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NI')">Nicaragua</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NO')">Norway</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NP')">Nepal</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NR')">Nauru</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NU')">Niue</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NZ')">New Zealand</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PA')">Panama</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PE')">Peru</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PF')">French Polynesia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PG')">Papua New Guinea</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PH')">Philippines</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PK')">Pakistan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PL')">Poland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PM')">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PN')">Pitcairn</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PR')">Puerto Rico</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PT')">Portugal</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PW')">Palau</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PY')">Paraguay</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('QA')">Qatar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('RE')">Réunion</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('RO')">Romania</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('RS')">Serbia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('RU')">Russian Federation</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SA')">Saudi Arabia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SB')">Solomon Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SE')">Sweden</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SG')">Singapore</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SH')">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SI')">Slovenia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SJ')">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SK')">Slovakia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SL')">Sierra Leone</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SM')">San Marino</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SN')">Senegal</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SR')">Suriname</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SS')">South Sudan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ST')">Sao Tome and Principe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SV')">El Salvador</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SX')">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SY')">Syrian Arab Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SZ')">Swaziland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TC')">Turks and Caicos Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TD')">Chad</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TF')">French Southern Territories</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TG')">Togo</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TH')">Thailand</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TJ')">Tajikistan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TK')">Tokelau</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TL')">Timor-Leste</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TM')">Turkmenistan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TO')">Tonga</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TR')">Turkey</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TT')">Trinidad and Tobago</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TV')">Tuvalu</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TW')">Taiwan, Province of China</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TZ')">Tanzania, United Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UA')">Ukraine</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UG')">Uganda</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UM')">United States Minor Outlying Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UY')">Uruguay</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UZ')">Uzbekistan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VA')">Holy See (Vatican City State)</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VC')">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VE')">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VN')">Viet Nam</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VU')">Vanuatu</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('WF')">Wallis and Futuna</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('WS')">Samoa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('YT')">Mayotte</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ZA')">South Africa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ZM')">Zambia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ZW')">Zimbabwe</a></li>
```

any tips would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Is this PHP or pure HTML?

Comment: If it's pure HTML do you have Excel?

Comment: pure HTML, I don't know PHP and i told my boss we should get this done in PHP.. but it wanted it done like this.

Comment: Got Excel installed?

Comment: @GouxLord not dupe, he's not looking for a JS solution

Comment: Yes I have excel.. Would that work.. i actually copied it into excel but thought because of the code it wouldn't allow me to sort.. am i wrong ?

Comment: I'll post you an Excel based answer ;)

Comment: I would like to change the tag from JavaScript to Excel

Comment: @mayersdesign, Do **not** edit questions to invalidate answers. Particularly, to make *your* answer appear to be correct. If the OP wants to ask a new question, that reflects their actual problem, then they should do so. People answered the original question, including the JavaScript tag, in good faith. Policy is that edits, even by the OP, which invalidate answers should be rolled back, by any user that has edit privileges. I have done so here. While it appears that the OP actually wants to manipulate text, that is a different question, with many tools, not just Excel, which could do the job.

Comment: @Makyen Suggesting I edited that tag to make my answer appear to be correct is a disgusting slur. I edited it after I saw "Sagar V" above make that suggestion - simply because I thought it was a good idea, and would help people find the information on the page, since the majority of the responses to the question turned out to be Excel based. In hindsight ADDING the excel tag and leaving the javascript one would have been even better, but my only intention was to make the whole question "tidier". I appreciate you retracting that slur, and I will now ADD an Excel tag.

Comment: @mayersdesign, I can see how you might read my comment as an accusation. It was not intended as one. However, the fact remains that what you did, adding the Excel tag and removing the JavaScript tag, did, in fact, invalidate all other answers (against policy) and made your answer the only one which was complying with the tags. Prior to the edit your answer was the only one *not* complying with the tags. No matter the motivations of your edit, those were the effects. You did this when the OP had only stated that they have Excel (& had copied it to Excel), not that they wanted an Excel solution.

Comment: @mayersdesign, Implying your edit was not influenced in the slightest by the fact that you had an answer which was benefited by the change is unrealistic. We're all human. Not having it affect your thinking in the slightest is near-impossible. My comment was intended to inform you, and others, about what the policy is regarding making edits to questions which cause answers to be invalidated, and explain my reverting the edit. It was also intended to point out to you how *you* making that edit had the *appearance* of being self-serving (no matter if that was your actual motivation).

Comment: @Makyen - Thanks for the (semi) apology, but in fact a central point in your comment is incorrect. I edited the question only AFTER my answer was marked correct by the OP. The timing of this edit is critical. Someone else even posted an Excel answer before me. As I said, I should not have removed the javascript tag, that was my error, and as you seem to accept, that was not done to further my own situation, in fact it was simply done to help other people... plus to be honest I'd never edited a tag before haha.

Comment: @Makyen - You've confused me. What benefit would my answer get... oh I see... you need to read my last comment. The change was made AFTER my answer was accepted. I saw no benefit in changing it other than the fact that someone else suggested it should be changed, and thought it would be the right thing to do. I understand your approach, but you got it wrong this time.

Comment: @mayersdesign, Changing tags to make one answer more correct (vs. other answers) results in that answer being more likely to be up-voted. Changing a question to invalidate answers makes those answers more likely to be down-voted (or not up-voted). This is the case without regard to your answer being accepted at the time of the edit. Unfortunately, a lot of this situation boils down to the question being poor in that it's unclear as to what is actually wanted. In a high volume tags like those used, easy questions often get multiple responses without waiting for clarification from the OP.

Comment: @user3546063, If you still desire answers with other possible solutions, then you should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you do, please be clear that you are wanting to sort the HTML text. You should also give information as to what constraints exist in your environment wrt. OS and what tools are available. There are *many* possible solutions (e.g. using the GNU command line program `sort --key=1.41` sorts the lines easily (be sure to set environment variable `LC_ALL` to your locale)). Without constraints, the question would be too broad.

Comment: @Makyen - I understand, I hadn't thought of it that way honestly. I thought tags were there to help people find things on the site, I guess I'm an organisation nut. Again I assure you I didn't edit it for an devious purpose, just because I thought the whole page was now more reasonably categorised "excel". I should also have left the JS tag, that was just an error. So let's leave it there. I'll be more careful in future, and I trust you now do not think I did it in an underhanded fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Excel to break apart blocks of code, sort or insert other data, then put back together!**

**1) Split the code block into columns**

- Copy code block to excel, go to data tab then "text to columns"
- Select "fixed width", and drag the slider to the edge of the country names (I am working fast here, you normally would use a delimiter)
- Hit "Finish"
- Select column B and hit "home tab" then "Sort and filter" - Sort A-Z saying "yes" to expand selection

**2) Put it back together again (concatenate)**

- Go to column on far right and click first empty cell (C)...
- Hit "Formulas", "Text", "CONCACTENATE"
- Select Cols A and B and hit "OK"
- Double click the corner of that formulae to copy it to the bottom of the sheet

**3) Remember that the formulas output is not yet "copyable" so...**

- Select all the output, copy and then go to the next column and hit "Paste Values"
- Then copy THAT column to your other program and you are done

That's it in a nutshell, but this technique is worth learning, I have "concatenation" sheets that I use constantly for all sorts of jobs :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortUL(selector) {
    var $ul = $(selector);
    $ul.find('li').sort(function (a, b) {
    var upA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var upB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return (upA < upB) ? -1 : (upA > upB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(selector);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    sortUL(".dropdown-menu");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function alphaBetSort(setClass) {
    var listofLi =jQuery(setClass).children();
    var data = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < listofLi.length; i++) {
        data.push(listofLi[i].textContent);
    }
    data.sort();
    data.forEach(function(content, index) {
        listofLi[index].textContent = content;
    });
}
// pass ul class in this function
alphaBetSort(".dropdown-menu");
```

Answer (score -1):

I did this using Excel. I copied your code into Excel, then run text to columns wizard. I split on the '>' character. This gave me a column with the country name. I then sorted all the data based on this column before combining back into strings.

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AX')">Aland Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AL')">Albania</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AD')">Andorra</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AI')">Anguilla</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AQ')">Antarctica</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AG')">Antigua and Barbuda</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AR')">Argentina</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AM')">Armenia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AU')">Australia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AT')">Austria</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('AZ')">Azerbaijan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BS')">Bahamas</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BD')">Bangladesh</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BB')">Barbados</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BY')">Belarus</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BE')">Belgium</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BJ')">Benin</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BM')">Bermuda</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BT')">Bhutan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BO')">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BA')">Bosnia and Herzegovina</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BW')">Botswana</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BV')">Bouvet Island</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BR')">Brazil</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IO')">British Indian Ocean Territory</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BN')">Brunei Darussalam</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BG')">Bulgaria</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BF')">Burkina Faso</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BI')">Burundi</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KH')">Cambodia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CM')">Cameroon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CA')">Canada</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CV')">Cape Verde</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KY')">Cayman Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CF')">Central African Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TD')">Chad</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CL')">Chile</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CN')">China</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CX')">Christmas Island</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CC')">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CO')">Colombia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KM')">Comoros</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CD')">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CG')">Congo</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CK')">Cook Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CR')">Costa Rica</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CI')">Côte d'Ivoire</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HR')">Croatia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CY')">Cyprus</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CZ')">Czech Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DK')">Denmark</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DJ')">Djibouti</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DM')">Dominica</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DO')">Dominican Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('EC')">Ecuador</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('EG')">Egypt</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SV')">El Salvador</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GQ')">Equatorial Guinea</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('EE')">Estonia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FK')">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FO')">Faroe Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FJ')">Fiji</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FI')">Finland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FR')">France</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GF')">French Guiana</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PF')">French Polynesia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TF')">French Southern Territories</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GA')">Gabon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GM')">Gambia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GE')">Georgia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('DE')">Germany</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GH')">Ghana</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GI')">Gibraltar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GR')">Greece</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GL')">Greenland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GD')">Grenada</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GP')">Guadeloupe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GU')">Guam</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GT')">Guatemala</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GG')">Guernsey</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GW')">Guinea-Bissau</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GN')">Guinea</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GY')">Guyana</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HT')">Haiti</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HM')">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VA')">Holy See (Vatican City State)</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HN')">Honduras</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HK')">Hong Kong</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('HU')">Hungary</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IS')">Iceland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IN')">India</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ID')">Indonesia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IR')">Iran, Islamic Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IE')">Ireland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IM')">Isle of Man</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('IT')">Italy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('JM')">Jamaica</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('JP')">Japan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('JE')">Jersey</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KZ')">Kazakhstan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KE')">Kenya</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KI')">Kiribati</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KP')">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KR')">Korea, Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KG')">Kyrgyzstan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LA')">Lao People's Democratic Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LV')">Latvia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LB')">Lebanon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LS')">Lesotho</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LY')">Libya</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LI')">Liechtenstein</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LT')">Lithuania</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LU')">Luxembourg</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MO')">Macao</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MK')">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MG')">Madagascar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MW')">Malawi</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MY')">Malaysia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MV')">Maldives</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ML')">Mali</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MQ')">Martinique</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MU')">Mauritius</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('YT')">Mayotte</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MX')">Mexico</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('FM')">Micronesia, Federated States of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MD')">Moldova, Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MC')">Monaco</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MN')">Mongolia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ME')">Montenegro</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MS')">Montserrat</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MA')">Morocco</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MZ')">Mozambique</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MM')">Myanmar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NA')">Namibia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NR')">Nauru</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NP')">Nepal</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NC')">New Caledonia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NZ')">New Zealand</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NI')">Nicaragua</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NE')">Niger</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NG')">Nigeria</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NU')">Niue</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('MP')">Northern Mariana Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('NO')">Norway</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PK')">Pakistan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PW')">Palau</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PA')">Panama</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PG')">Papua New Guinea</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PY')">Paraguay</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PE')">Peru</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PH')">Philippines</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PN')">Pitcairn</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PL')">Poland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PT')">Portugal</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PR')">Puerto Rico</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('QA')">Qatar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('RE')">Réunion</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('RO')">Romania</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('RU')">Russian Federation</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('BL')">Saint Barthélemy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SH')">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('KN')">Saint Kitts and Nevis</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LC')">Saint Lucia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('PM')">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VC')">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('WS')">Samoa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SM')">San Marino</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ST')">Sao Tome and Principe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SA')">Saudi Arabia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SN')">Senegal</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('RS')">Serbia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SL')">Sierra Leone</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SG')">Singapore</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SX')">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SK')">Slovakia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SI')">Slovenia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SB')">Solomon Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ZA')">South Africa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SS')">South Sudan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ES')">Spain</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('LK')">Sri Lanka</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SR')">Suriname</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SJ')">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SZ')">Swaziland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SE')">Sweden</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('CH')">Switzerland</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('SY')">Syrian Arab Republic</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TW')">Taiwan, Province of China</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TJ')">Tajikistan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TZ')">Tanzania, United Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TH')">Thailand</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TL')">Timor-Leste</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TG')">Togo</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TK')">Tokelau</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TO')">Tonga</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TT')">Trinidad and Tobago</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TR')">Turkey</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TM')">Turkmenistan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TC')">Turks and Caicos Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('TV')">Tuvalu</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UG')">Uganda</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UA')">Ukraine</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('GB')">United Kingdom</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UM')">United States Minor Outlying Islands</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UY')">Uruguay</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('UZ')">Uzbekistan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VU')">Vanuatu</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VE')">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('VN')">Viet Nam</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('WF')">Wallis and Futuna</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('EH')">Western Sahara</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ZM')">Zambia</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('ZW')">Zimbabwe</a></li>
```

Comment: wow, I was going to show him how to do that :)

Comment: absolute legend !  - Thank you. How did ya do it ?

Comment: yes.. as @mayersdesign said please tell me how.. so i learn how. thanks.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. It just does the work without explaining *how* to do the work. It states the tool used, but not how to use the tool (which is non-trivial).

Comment: @Makyen I've added an explanation, to be honest I was a bit bored so decided to do the legwork for the OP